# three.js: Cylinder with negative thetaLength

Tags: three.js

I want to use an "inverted" cylinder with the thetaLength set to -6.3 so that the inside will be classed as the FrontSide, so then that cylinder can go inside another normal cylinder with rings on the top and bottom to form a tube.

The reason I want to do all this is so the whole object can be combined into one mesh with a single material. If you don't set the thetaLength to negative you have to have a duplicate material with the side set to BackSide, so you can't have it all as one mesh.

I've done what I'm talking about in the example below (you can zoom and move with the mouse). The negative theta cylinder is on the left and the normal one is on the right.

The problem that I'm having is, you can see that cylinder in question (the inside) of the left one is much darker than on the right one. The right one looks much more realistic.

I'm thinking maybe it's because it thinks the light is coming from a different direction to where it's actually coming from.

Is there any way to fix this and make the inverted cylinder appear like the BackSide one so that I can have a tube like this as a single mesh?

```js
width = window.innerWidth
height = window.innerHeight

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true})
renderer.setClearColor(0x8e8ed7)
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)
renderer.setSize(width, height)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

scene = new THREE.Scene()
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, width / height, 0.1, 3000)
camera.position.set(0, 50, 100)

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera)
controls.minDistance = 40
controls.maxDistance = 1300

scene.add(camera, new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.48))
light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.55)

light.position.copy( camera.position );
light.position.y -= 80
light.position.x += 100
camera.add(light)

requestAnimationFrame(function animate(){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
})

material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xFF7E14, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 75})
material2= new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xFF7E14, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 75, side: THREE.BackSide})

tube_a = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(6,6,20,32,1,true,0,-6.3), material)
tube_aa = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(6,6,20,32,1,true,0,6.3), material2)
tube_b = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(8.1375,8.1375,20,32,1,true), material)
ring = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.RingGeometry(6,8.1375,32), material)

group1 = new THREE.Group()

ta1 = tube_a.clone()
group1.add(ta1)
tb1 = tube_b.clone()
group1.add(tb1)
r = ring.clone()
r.position.y -= 10
r.rotateX((9*Math.PI)/18)
group1.add(r)
r = ring.clone()
r.position.y += 10
r.rotateX((27*Math.PI)/18)
group1.add(r)
group1.position.x -= 15
scene.add(group1)

group2 = new THREE.Group()

ta2 = tube_aa.clone()
group2.add(ta2)
tb2 = tube_b.clone()
group2.add(tb2)
r = ring.clone()
r.position.y -= 10
r.rotateX((9*Math.PI)/18)
group2.add(r)
r = ring.clone()
r.position.y += 10
r.rotateX((27*Math.PI)/18)
group2.add(r)
group2.position.x += 15
scene.add(group2)
```

```html
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Negative values for `thetaLength` are not supported since this leads to wrong normal vectors. That's the reason for the wrong lighting in your demo. You have to adjust the source code of `CylinderGeometry` or use a modeling tool to solve this problem. I suggest the latter option.

Comment: It turns out you can just do `Geometry.computeVertexNormals()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem that I'm having is, you can see that cylinder in question (the inside) of the left one is much darker than on the right one. The right one looks much more realistic.

You have to update the vertex normal vectors by [`Geometry.computeVertexNormals()`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Geometry.computeVertexNormals) after generating the mesh, to solve this issue:

```
tube_a = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(6,6,20,32,1,true,0,-6.3), material)
tube_a.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

```js
width = window.innerWidth
height = window.innerHeight

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true})
renderer.setClearColor(0x8e8ed7)
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio)
renderer.setSize(width, height)
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement)

scene = new THREE.Scene()
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(35, width / height, 0.1, 3000)
camera.position.set(0, 50, 100)

controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera)
controls.minDistance = 40
controls.maxDistance = 1300

scene.add(camera, new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.48))
light = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 0.55)

light.position.copy( camera.position );
light.position.y -= 80
light.position.x += 100
camera.add(light)

requestAnimationFrame(function animate(){
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
  renderer.render(scene, camera)
})

material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xFF7E14, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 75})
material2= new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color: 0xFF7E14, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 75, side: THREE.BackSide})

tube_a = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(6,6,20,32,1,true,0,-6.3), material)
tube_a.geometry.computeVertexNormals();

tube_aa = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(6,6,20,32,1,true,0,6.3), material2)
tube_b = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.CylinderGeometry(8.1375,8.1375,20,32,1,true), material)
ring = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.RingGeometry(6,8.1375,32), material)




group1 = new THREE.Group()

ta1 = tube_a.clone()
group1.add(ta1)
tb1 = tube_b.clone()
group1.add(tb1)
r = ring.clone()
r.position.y -= 10
r.rotateX((9*Math.PI)/18)
group1.add(r)
r = ring.clone()
r.position.y += 10
r.rotateX((27*Math.PI)/18)
group1.add(r)
group1.position.x -= 15
scene.add(group1)

group2 = new THREE.Group()

ta2 = tube_aa.clone()
group2.add(ta2)
tb2 = tube_b.clone()
group2.add(tb2)
r = ring.clone()
r.position.y -= 10
r.rotateX((9*Math.PI)/18)
group2.add(r)
r = ring.clone()
r.position.y += 10
r.rotateX((27*Math.PI)/18)
group2.add(r)
group2.position.x += 15
scene.add(group2)

function resize() {
    
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = aspect;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    //controls.handleResize();
  }

window.onresize = resize;
```

```html
<script src="http://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's perfect! I thought I was going to have to copy over all the vertices into a new geometry and make new faces. That's saved me a load of time.